# C# Reference dynamically created image in completion event

Tags: c#, wpf

I've dynamically created a series of images in a loop, along with an animation and Storyboard for each, and I'm looking to remove the image once the animation is complete. The image, animation and storyboard are stored in arrays for reference.

The animations have different durations and there are other elements on the canvas that I don't want removed.

This is the code I've got to generate the images, animations and storyboards:

```
for (int i = 0; i < apples.Length; i++)
{
  Image apple = new Image();
  apple.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/fall;component/Resources/apple.png"));
  apple.Height = 48;
  apple.Width = 48;

  int x = r.Next(5, (int)cGame.ActualWidth - 53);
  int y = (int)cGame.ActualHeight - 48;

  Canvas.SetLeft(apple, x);
  Canvas.SetTop(apple, y);

  apples[i] = apple;

}

for(int i = 0; i < speeds.Length; i++)
{
  DoubleAnimation speed = new DoubleAnimation();
  speed.From = 0;
  speed.To = cGame.ActualHeight;
  speed.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, r.Next(2, 6) * 500);

  speeds[i] = speed;
  speeds[i].Completed += new EventHandler(aniComplete);
}

for (int i = 0; i < sbs.Length; i++)
{
  Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
  sb.Children.Add(speeds[i]);
  Storyboard.SetTarget(speeds[i], apples[i]);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(speeds[i], new PropertyPath(TopProperty));

  sbs[i] = sb;
}
```

So far I've created a completed event and attached it to each animation. I'm removing elements using this:

```
canvas.Children.RemoveAt(1);
```

But it just removed the elements in order, skipping an element that I want to keep. The animations are running at a random time and have a random duration, so its easily possible that the elements can complete their animation out of order.

How would I reference the specific element in the completed event? I tried referencing sender but I'm not sure what I should cast it to as (UIElement) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the `Completed` event handler from a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that captures the appropriate variables, i.e. the Canvas and the appropriate Image control:

```
speeds[i].Completed += (o, e) => canvas.Children.Remove(apples[i]);
```

Please refer to the *Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions* section in [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more information.